# Pocketsphinx with raspberry pi 2

Tags: pi-2

May i know how to install Pocket SPHINX into raspberry pi 2? Can someone provide the link tutorial to me?

Comment: have you tried sudo apt-get install pocketsphinx?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it install on mind using this:

https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/embedded/raspberrypi2-sr/

Comment: Link only answers while technically correct are not ideal, they become useless if the link breaks. Perhaps you could summarise the information on that webpage in your answer?